# Загрузка модуля pf_ring при запуске Debian

Tags: debian

Использую драйвер сетевой карты igb, но для корректной работы перед этим драйвером должен быть загружен модуль pf_ring. Если просто добавить pf_ring в /etc/modules, то он загружается уже после igb, и ничего не работает.

Как сделать, чтобы сначала загружался pf_ring, а только потом уже igb?

Answer (score 1):

В Linux нет прямого метода управления порядком загрузки модулей ядра (за исключением случае, когда они являются прямыми зависимостями друг друга, и тогда порядок отражает эти зависимости), но есть известный способ обхода описанной вами проблемы.

1. Вы добавляете модуль который должен загружаться вторым (igb) в файл `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`;
2. Вы добавляете в файл `/etc/modules` сначала первый модуль `pf_ring`, а потом второй `igb`.

В этом случае они загружаются в нужно порядке.

Если нужна более сложная последовательность загрузки, не просто один раньше другого, то нужно написать скрипт, который вызывать в соответствующем месте.

Подробнее об описанной методике:

- [Linux: Adjust storage kernel module load order](https://major.io/2009/01/26/linux-adjust-storage-kernel-module-load-order/) (англ.)

Comment: Пробовал, почему-то не работает. Добавлял igb в /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist, писал blacklist igb в /etc/modprobe.d/pf_ring.conf - все равно он его подгружает раньше, и даже тогда, когда он не прописан в /etc/modules.

Система -   3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux